# Trouble sending request body in webhook end-point for stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Here's the flow:

- Hit the stripe checkout end-point
- If the payment was successful, send an email to user

Email includes:

- Customer Name
- Starting date
- Ending date

So, far I'm able to hit the stripe checkout end-point then redirecting the user to that page and make the payment. But, I'm unable to pass the parameters that are required in the email to be sent.

#### Stripe Function

```js
app.post('/stripe-checkout', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let baseUrl = req.query.env == 'prod' ? 'https://leaf-for-business.web.app' : 'http://localhost:8080';
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            line_items: [
                {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: 'usd',
                        product_data: {
                            name: 'Promotion Payment',
                        },
                        unit_amount: req.query.amount * 100, /// 1USD = 100 Cents
                    },
                    quantity: 1,
                }
            ],
            mode: 'payment',
            payment_method_types: [ "card" ],
            success_url: baseUrl + '/home',
        });

        res.send({
            success: true,
            session_id: session.id,
            redirect_url: session.url,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({
            success: false,
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
});
```

#### Webhook Function

```js
app.post('/webhook', (request, response) => {
    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

    const endpointSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;
    let event;

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
        response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
        return;
    }

    // Handle the event
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'checkout.session.completed':
            const checkoutSessionCompleted = event.data.object;
            sendEmail(request.body); /// <<-- HERE'S THE PROBLEM
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
    }

    // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    response.send();
});
```

#### Email Send

```js
async function sendEmail(body) {
    const DOMAIN = "app.joinleaf.com";
    const SENDER_EMAIL = "no-reply@app.joinleaf.com";

    const mailgun = new Mailgun(formData);
    const mg = mailgun.client({
        username: 'api',
        key: process.env.MG_PRIVATE_KEY,
        host: "api.eu.mailgun.net",
    });

    const customerEmail = body.email;
    const customerName = body.customer_name;

    //
    const startDate = body.start_date;
    const endDate = body.end_date;

    const emailBody = fs.readFileSync('src/email.html', 'utf8').toString();
    const finalTemp = emailBody.replaceAll('customer-name', customerName)
        .replace('start-date', startDate)
        .replace('end-date', endDate);

    const messageData = {
        from: SENDER_EMAIL,
        // to: [customerEmail, "team@getleaflets.co"],
        to: [customerEmail, "team@getleaflets.co"],
        // bcc: ["getleaflets.co"],
        subject: "Thank you for your purchase.",
        html: finalTemp,
    };

    const resp = await mg.messages.create(DOMAIN, messageData, (err, body) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Sent! ' + body);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    return resp;
}
```

Now, how can I send the name, start and end date to webhook so that it can be passed to email function if the payment is a success

Answer (score 1):

Really you should be passing the `checkoutSessionCompleted` variable you created to your `sendEmail` function like `sendEmail(checkoutSessionCompleted)` instead of what you have.
That object is the CheckoutSession object for the successful payment which you're handling from the webhook and everything in it is fully documented — it will have all the fields explained at https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object

So inside `sendEmail`, the email address the customer used is available, same with the name and so on.

- `body.customer_email` -> customer's email -> https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_email
- `body.customer_details.name` -> customer's entered name -> https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_details-name

And so on, you can look at the Stripe API reference to see what's in the object.

Comment: Understood, but I want to send `start_date` and `end_date` alongside. I've all the values from the checkoutSessionCompleted which you mentioned as well. But unable to figure out how to pass the rest of them

Comment: What are start_date and end_date?

Comment: `Date()` objects

Answer (score 0):

The webhook will have the exact data that is on the Checkout Session object. If you want to add arbitrary values to the Checkout Session object you can set them as `metadata` on the Session when you are creating it[1].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

Comment: I'm using checkout session and checkout session doesn't have any parameter like `meta` or `meta_data`. Its in `payment_intent` call for stripe.